# Get the owner of thread that is executing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

when I run the project I receive the famous "Calling thread cannot access..." exception. Now, first I would like to see why is this happening, since my code should not be creating this new thread at this stage, so I would like to know who created this thread.

When exception occurs, StackTrace reports that the method was called from external code (only two items in StackTrace).

Threads window reports its Priority only (no explanation in Name).

How can I get more information about the current thread running? Like which library created it? Is it external code or mine?

Comment: Invoke "Find Usages" on that method to see what code is referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.CurrentThread` should tell you all what you need to know about a managed thread. If "Threads window" doesn't shows name means, there is no name specified.

Also there is no way you could find which library created the thread. No such information stored anywhere.